# How Can I name a list inside a 'FOR' loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

I have to use a FOR loop like this

```
x=0
for i in range(22):
    SOME OPERATION
```

And than store the value of operation in a list like [0,0,0,0,0]
depending upon the OPERATION results +1 will be done to any of 5 values in list.

The problem is that I need a list for every iteration. Could you please help me with naming/initializing a list with name like list1, list2 and so on till list 22. SO that I can keep on +1 to list at any of five values

AK

Comment: Please elaborate (edit your post) on what you are really trying to do. It is difficult to understand. If you need to define an arbitrary number of things, use a dictionary or a list of lists. For example, `myLists[i] = [0,0,0,0,0]`. Otherwise please elaborate since there is almost certainly a better way to do this, probably even a one-liner.

Comment: How self similar will these lists be? Do you have an example operation you'd like to mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a group of named lists then it sounds like you want a dictionary:

```
myLists = dict()
for x in range(22):
    myLists[ 'list%d' % x ] = [0,0,0,0,0]
```

If you'd rather do it with a list of lists:

```
myLists = list()
for x in range(22):
    myLists.append( [0,0,0,0,0] )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(22):
    myLists[i] = [0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Hi, Ninja,I am getting the following error with your method:                                                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 2, in <module>
    pos[i]=[0,0,0,0,0]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @AtulKakrana: this method assumes you have initialized your array to something, e.g. `myLists = [None for _ in range(22)]`, though I still have no idea what you are trying to do, so can't give specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `lists` variable on the top:

```
lists = [list1, list2, ... ,list22]

x=0
for i in range(22):
    SOME OPERATION against lists[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory one-liner:

(Where `operation()` returns `[0,0,0,0]`)

**Dict**

```
mydict = {num : operation() for num in range(22)}

{0: [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 1: [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 2: [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 3: [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 ...,     
 21: [0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

**List**

```
mylist = [operation() for num in range(22)]

[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 ...,
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```